# Counting status of a variable in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a Excel as below:

[image]

wanted to count number of passed/failed status against bookings and de-bookings separately as in here Bookings - Passed =1, failed=1;
De-Bookings - Passed=1, failed=1 in a separate sheet.
The order of bookings and de-bookings cannot be controlled.

I have tried with "CountIf" function but that gives me total number of bookings or de-bookings. Would be helpful if I can do this without VBA.

Comment: Countifs allows you to specify more than one criteria

Comment: @chrisneilsen: worked, exploring further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in **F2** and drag/copy it to the right and then select **F2** to **G2** and drag/copy it down:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E2,$C:$C,F$1)
```

[image]

Comment: It worked, thanks. one more query suppose if I want to display this count into another sheet would below be the formula, also can i use a "Passed/failed" directly in the formula?
=COUNTIFS(Test_Execution_Results!$A:$A,"BookingsBO",$C:$C,"PASSED")
"Test_Execution_Results" is where my base data resides.

Comment: @Vinod of course, you can hardcode any of the criteria, except the range, which should be prefixed the sheet name.